# How to set the JText field with the JLabel clicked?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlabel, jtextfield

How can I set the `JTextField` with the `JLabel` just clicked?

What should I add in:

```
 public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
      jLabel2MouseClicked(evt);
 } 

 private void jLabel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

 }
```

Comment: Could you add some more context to your example code, such as fields?  Also, I'm suspicious that you're allowing the user to click on labels.

Comment: yes I am allowing the user to click on the labels.and after clicking I want the label to be set in the JtextField.

Comment: This seems a bit weird but you could simple make the jLabel invisible when you click on it ( setVisible(false) ) and then make the Jtextfield positioned at the same place visible. Not really sure why you would take that approach though.

Comment: no my jtextfield is not positioned at the same place. Its like you enter a keyword in the jtextfield and then all the related words cum as output in the form of jlabels, Now the user can click on one of the jlabels and that label should get set in the jtextfield now.

Comment: Well, I assume you could use something like `this.textField.setText(((JLabel)evt.getComponent()).getText())`.  But still - will the users know to click on the labels, which are otherwise _never_ used to provide input?

Comment: then instead of Jlabels what else can I use to show the clickable text

Comment: You can make labels look like hyperlinks, this will invite a click. Or you can change cursor once over the label. Or you can simply use buttons. Or maybe flat style buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also question the reasons for allowing clicking on labels. Why not use buttons?

Anyway, assuming you do have a good reason, this is how you could do it:

```
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label 1");
    final JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label 2");
    final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            textField.setText(((JLabel) e.getSource()).getText());
        }

    };
    label1.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    label2.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    frame.add(label1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(label2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```